# Create capsule-style toolbar controls in Qt

Tags: macos, qt, user-interface, toolbar

What is the best way to render [capsule-style toolbar controls](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGControls/XHIGControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-SW8) (including the label text below the buttons) in a Qt application?

As far as rendering the buttons, I want to tap into what is provided by Mac OS as much as possible. (I'm not a Mac developer, so do not know if it has an API for this.) That is, I know I can draw them myself, use style sheets for border-image, guess on the font, and set it all up in a layout, but is there a better way that ensures consistent presentation when Mac updates her "look and feel?" I am using C++ in Qt.

I don't hate the idea of using Q_WS_MAC to get the platform-specific rendering, but does Qt already have anything for this? You know, a `setCapsuleStyle(true)` method somewhere? :)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a segmented button example in the qt-labs repository that looks decent on KDE. It has a fair amount of `#ifdef Q_WS_MAC` code, but I don't know how well it renders on Mac. You can find it [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/%7bnon-gerrit%7d/qt-labs/segmentedbutton.git/).

If you are specifically targeting only Mac, you may use the [QMacCocoaViewContainer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmaccocoaviewcontainer.html) to render native segmented buttons. Its learning curve is quite steep, so you may find this Qt Labs Blog post about Mac widget interesting: [Mac widget style addons](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/04/17/mac-widget-style-addons/). The author provides three Mac-style widgets: QtCocoaPushButton, QtCocoaComboBox and QtCocoaSegmentedButton.

Answer (score 1):

As Qt doesn't provide this type of widget by itself, the best way would be subclassing QPushButton and reimplementing `paintEvent`. You can then draw your capsule pixmap by simply painting a QPixmap that contains a screenshot of the capsule button. You can add click behaviour by reimplementing `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`.

```
// CapsuleButton.h
class CapsuleButton : public QPushPutton {
   // ...
protected:
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*);
   void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*);
   // ...
private:
   QPixmap pixmap_;
   QPixmap pressedPixmap_;
   bool pressed_;
};

// CapsuleButton.cpp
CapsuleButton::CapsuleButton(QObject* parent) : 
    QPushButton(parent),
    pixmap_(":/capsule-button-background.png"),
    pressedPixmap_(":/capsule-button-background-pressed.png"),
    pressed_(false)
{ /*...*/ }

void CapsuleButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(rect(), pressed_? pressedPixmap_ : pixmap_);
}

void CapsuleButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
       pressed_ = true;
    update();
}

void CapsuleButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
    pressed_ = false;
    update();
}
```

I have writte a short tutorial on how to create custom widgets: http://www.serenethinking.com/2010/08/how-to-create-custom-widgets-with-qt/

Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar stuff in past. Unfortunately I don't have its source code with me to share with you. However most safest bet is to use [Qt Style sheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-reference.html). They support various properties, pseudo-states, and subcontrols that make it possible to customize the look to any extend.